# How to launch other android apps using the flutter app

Tags: flutter

I have used the following method as specified in the documentation.

```
  Future<void> launchUniversalLink(String url) async {
    if (await canLaunch(url)) {
      final bool nativeAppLaunchSuccess = await launch(url, forceSafariVC: false, universalLinksOnly: true);
      print(nativeAppLaunchSuccess);
    }else {
      print('launch not successfull');
    }
  }
```

if I give URL = 'https://www.WhatsApp.com'

```
  print(nativeAppLaunchSuccess); output ==> true
```

but still the app launches in the browser.
can anyone help me with this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh I'm sorry. This is my mistake.
Please use 'device_apps' flutter package and usage is below.

And here is a how to know app package name.
https://www.techmesto.com/find-android-app-package-name/

In ios, you know other app's custom Url schema that officially opened.
But usually we can not know that url.
So below ios code is executed, it will open appstore page and need to push 'open' button.

```
if (Platform.isAndroid) {
  if (await DeviceApps.isAppInstalled('com.nbt.moves') ==
      true) {
    DeviceApps.openApp('com.nbt.moves');
  } 
} else {
      const url =
        'https://apps.apple.com/kr/app/%EC%BA%90%EC%8B%9C%EC%8A%AC%EB%9D%BC%EC%9D%B4%EB%93%9C-%EC%8A%A4%ED%85%9D%EC%97%85/id1400703652?uo=4';
    if (await canLaunch(url)) {
      await launch(url);
    } else {
      throw 'Could not launch $url';
    }
}
```

Comment: How to use this package for ios?